# How does sizeof wоrk in this case?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 1;
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(int[++i]));
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

I was testing the `sizeof` operator because variable-length array type operands are evaluated — *I would be happy if someone gives clarification on this as well but the question is different*.

6.5.3.4/2

The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined by the type of the operand. The result is an integer. **If the type of the operand is a variable-length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant**.

The output of the above code on GCC is as follows:

```
8
2
```

Can someone please explain where this 8 comes from? Does the array decay into a pointer?
Please also give clarification on the variable-length array part.

Comment: `int[++i]` becomes `int[2]` in your code. So `sizeof(int[++i])` is the same as `2 * sizeof(int)` which gave you that **8** because the `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your machine.

Comment: @Ardent Coder Please tell me why does this require only ```int[++i]``` and doesn't require an *array name* something like ```int a[++i]```.

Comment: It is just the **type** that matters to `sizeof`. Just like `int*` denotes an integer pointer (without specifying a name like you often see in function prototypes), `int[2]` denotes an integer array of size two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time `int[++i]` is evaluated, `i` initially has the value 1.  So `int[++i]` evaluates to `int[2]`, i.e. an array of `int` of size 2.

Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes on your system, this array is 8 bytes in size.

Answer (score 4):

An int is 4 byte long. You are are passing the sizeof operatore an int Array of length 2. To store an int Array of 2 you need 2x4 = 8 Bytes.

```
++i
```

increments the value of i from 1 to 2 before it is used. That's why your output is 8 and 2.

Comment: "*An int is 4 byte long.*" for the OP, not in general, better to be more clear

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function. It is an operator.

Comment: @bruno what do you mean with OP?

Comment: @ArdentCoder my bad. You were right. I edited it in my post.

Comment: @MarvinKlein OP means original poster. Bruno meant that `sizeof int` is compiler dependent.